# My simple neural network struggles to learn a linear function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am generating artificial data on which I experiment with a neural network. The goal will be to look for complex non linear signal, but at first I want my network to learn the linear signal, so I use just one Dense layer with 1 output and linear activation. I have 10^6 data points for training, 10^5 for validation, and only 8 features, which are not very highly correlated, so I expect the weights to converge to the solution of linear regression quite easily. Instead, this does not happen; I achieve correlation between my predictions and the true values that are close to a linear model on the training sample, but on validation I get stuck in what looks like a local minimum of the loss.

I experimented a bit with changing the learning rate, but the results were not good, so I'll leave that part out. Here is the code to reproduce it all, it's easier if you copy the code in a jupyter notebook. I included the data generation code for reproducibility, the reason I do it this way is not important (has to do with non linear signal).

Would anyone have any useful insight?

```
### Import libraries, set seed

import numpy as np, pandas as pd, statsmodels.api as sm, tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Input, layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
np.random.seed(2)


# Generate data

n_train = 1000000; n_valid = n_train//10; n_tot = n_train+n_valid
g1 = np.random.randn(n_tot + 1)
r = np.sqrt(0.95)*g1[1:] + np.sqrt(0.05)*g1[:-1]; 

c1 = np.random.uniform(0.0,0.8,size = n_tot)
p1 = c1 * g1[:-1] + np.random.randn(n_tot); p1 = p1 / np.std(p1)

c2 = np.random.uniform(0.0,0.2,size = n_tot)
p2 = c2 * g1[:-1] + np.random.randn(n_tot); p2 = p2 / np.std(p2)

c3 = np.random.uniform(0.0,0.5,size = n_tot)
p3 = c3 * g1[:-1] + np.random.randn(n_tot); p3 = p3 / np.std(p3)

c4 = np.random.uniform(0.0,0.3,size = n_tot)
p4 = c4 * g1[:-1] + np.random.randn(n_tot); p4 = p4 / np.std(p4)

train_data = pd.DataFrame({"r" : r[:n_train]
                           , "p1" : p1[:n_train], "c1" : c1[:n_train]
                           , "p2" : p2[:n_train], "c2" : c2[:n_train]
                           , "p3" : p3[:n_train], "c3" : c3[:n_train]
                           , "p4" : p2[:n_train], "c4" : c4[:n_train]
                          })
valid_data = pd.DataFrame({"r" : r[n_train:n_train+n_valid]
                           , "p1" : p1[n_train:n_train+n_valid], "c1" : c1[n_train:n_train+n_valid]
                           , "p2" : p2[n_train:n_train+n_valid], "c2" : c2[n_train:n_train+n_valid]
                           , "p3" : p3[n_train:n_train+n_valid], "c3" : c3[n_train:n_train+n_valid]
                           , "p4" : p4[n_train:n_train+n_valid], "c4" : c4[n_train:n_train+n_valid]
                          }, index=np.arange(n_train, n_train+n_valid))


### Fit linear model and check correlation on the validation set

label_column = "r"
feature_columns = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
y_train = train_data[label_column].values
x_train = train_data[feature_columns].values
y_valid = valid_data[label_column].values
x_valid = valid_data[feature_columns].values

OLS = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train)
result=OLS.fit()
result.summary()
predictions = result.predict(x_valid)
print("Linear model validation correlation: ", np.corrcoef(y_valid, predictions)[0,1])


### Fit a single-layer, linear activation NN on the data

def correlation(y_true, y_pred):
    m_true = K.mean(y_true)
    m_pred = K.mean(y_pred)
    y_true_demeaned = y_true - m_true
    y_pred_demeaned = y_pred - m_pred
    return K.sum(y_true_demeaned*y_pred_demeaned) / K.sqrt(K.sum(y_true_demeaned*y_true_demeaned) * K.sum(y_pred_demeaned*y_pred_demeaned))

label_column = "r"; feature_columns = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
y_train = train_data[label_column].values; x_train = train_data[feature_columns].values
y_valid = valid_data[label_column].values; x_valid = valid_data[feature_columns].values

input_tensor = Input(shape=(len(feature_columns),))
output_tensor = layers.Dense(1, use_bias = False)(input_tensor)
model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)

RMSprop = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop,loss = "mean_squared_error", metrics = [correlation])
display(model.summary())

model.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=100, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid])
```

Comment: Though you can technically think of this as a special case of a neural network, it isn't really useful to do so. You're just comparing an exact method and an approximate method for finding the linear regression coefficients to minimize MSE. If you really want to make this work, for educational purposes, I'd start with a large batch size (even your full dataset) and just use vanilla SGD instead of RMSProp. Play with the learning rate until it works. Then you can look at the effects of decreasing the batch size (and changing the LR) and after that using different optimizers.

Comment: @Nathan It is partially for educational purposes but not just that. Most of the signal in my real world application will be in a linear signal, but there's a bit extra non linear signal to capture. If the network is bad at finding the linear signal, this will be a problem.

With SGD optimizer, large batch size, the validation loss gets stuck on weird values. I thought since there's a strong linear signal and lots of data, my intuition says this network should find the linear signal easily in a way that's robust to optimizer, learning rate and batch size, but it doesn't seem so...